# Get value of object property inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have array of objects:

```
var ads = [
{   
    adName: "Football Team",
    adText: ["....","...."],
    adImg: ["images/img1.png", "images/img2.png", "", "", ""],
    adPreviewLink: "templateA",
    adSeconds: 15,
    adTime: ad1Time
},{
    adName: "Basketball Team",
    adText: ["...","..."],
    adImg: ["images/img-b1.png", "images/img-b2.png", "", "", ""],
    adPreviewLink: "templateB",
    adSeconds: 10,
    adTime: ad2Time

}];
```

adTime property is also an object:

```
var ad1Time = {
    hours: ["6","12"],
    day: [weekdaysEnum.monday, weekdaysEnum.wednsday],
    month: [monthEnum.march, monthEnum.april],
    year: 2016,
    daysNumber: []
}
```

now i want to check the adTime>>year, but I am getting an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined

Here is how i tried to check the property:

```
var date = new Date();
var now_day = date.getDate();
var now_month = date.getMonth();
var now_year = date.getFullYear();

for (var i = 0; i < ads.length; i++) {
    if (ads[i].adTime.year == now_year) {
        for(var index_month; index_month < ads[i].adTime.month.length; index_month++)
        {
            if(ads[i].adTime.month[index_month] == now_month)
                console.log(ads[i].adName);
        }
    }

}
```

So where is the mistake(the mistake here: ads[i].adTime.year)? Thanks.

Comment: yes of course. it's look the same like ad1Time

Comment: code looks alright. Can you create a plunkr? Or maybe share the data...

Comment: man show us full code. u should first define a var and then use it. i guess u have defined ad1Time , ad2Time after ads

Comment: you are write. i defined the objects after the array of objects.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define 'ad1Time' and 'ad2Time' before 'ads'.